# Need to copy files from OneDrive on local machine to a network drive

Tags: windows-10

I tried this simple bat file and is giving me an invalid number of parameters:

```
@ECHO OFF
XCOPY C:\Users\XXXXX\OneDrive - XXXXXX, Inc\to network drive \\XXXXXXXXXXX\team_shares\XXXX XXX\XXX logo
Pause
```

I am totally new to this. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If the path source or destiny have spaces you have to use quotes...

```
XCOPY /i  "C:\Users\XXXXX\OneDrive - XXXXXX, Inc\*" "\\XXXXXXXXXXX\team_shares\XXXX XXX\XXX logo"
```

Comment: a simple solution for you big difference for me, thanks a lot it works,

Comment: Is it possible to run this bat from a phone? saving files from phone folder into a network folder?

Comment: @ninja vr: don't think phones can run batch files...

Comment: understand thanks!